# How to align a header and a paragraph beside an image

Tags: html, css

I want to have an image on the left and the header beside it on the top and have a paragraph under the header.

Example: [Link](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1gHiRa9kQ6A2Z3oFP2zZMZxvkHONHjOFXS9mlsxgMBN0/edit?usp=sharing)

Code I have right now:

```css
.code {
 margin-left: 10%;
 clear: left;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.code h1 {
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: 'Kurale', serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin-left: 20px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.code p {
 font-family: 'Spectral', serif;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.code img {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="code">
<img src="code.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border-radius:15%; overflow:hidden;">
<h1>Website Development:</h1>
<p>We do stuff</p>
</div>
<div class="code">
<img src="game.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border-radius:15%; overflow:hidden;">
<h1>Game Development</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depend on what behavior you want when your left or right columns are longer, but it looks like you're trying to have a table behavior with 2 cols...

```css
.container {
  display:table ;
}

.code {
  display:table-row ;
}

.code .left,
.code .right{
display:table-cell ;
vertical-align:top ;
}

.code .left { width:100px ; }

.left img { width:100px ; height:100px ; background:blue ; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="code">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="code.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>Website Development:</h1>
      <p>We do stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="code">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="game.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>Game Development</h1>
      <p>We do stuff</p>
      <p>We do stuff</p>
      <p>We do stuff</p>
      <p>We do stuff</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the markup is to add `float: left` to the image you want.

Your image new code will be:

```css
.code {
  margin-left: 10%;
  clear: left;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.code img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.code h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Kurale', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.code p {
  font-family: 'Spectral', serif;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="code">
  <img src="code.jpg">
  <h1>Website Development:</h1>
  <p>We do stuff</p>
</div>
<div class="code">
  <img src="game.jpg">
  <h1>Game Development</h1>
</div>
```